# How do I respond to a prompt after using & to make a new process?

Tags: linux, background-process, input

For example, if I want to create an ssh tunnel and not make it take up my terminal I could use `ssh -L 20000:localhost:2000 user@example.com &`. However, this creates a new process and doesn't let me enter a password. (I know I could use key authentication but this is a general question about `&`)

Comment: Terminals are cheap, and things like `screen` or `tmux` exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. At least not directly. `&` starts a background process. You can interact with foreground processes only. You could, however, start the process as foreground, do your password authentication, stop it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and set it to background with the command `bg $PID`.

Comment: This will be hard to do with ssh since once the session is started, CTRL+Z will be sent to the remote system instead of the local one.  The OP could either use the -f option on the ssh command to tell it to background itself after getting the password, or use ssh keys to avoid the password entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to login with ssh without entering password, you should create ssh key without a password and place the public portion of the key on the remote system.

Here is link on creating the ssh key.

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html